# Sorting Algorithm Explanation Complexity and Type

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

This is a sorting algorithm in Java. I have to analyze this algorithm but I'm really new to the subject and not sure about what each line does. I know that it's of the complexity of `O(N²)` but I don't understand what type it is.
Could someone please explain the method `someAlgorithm()`?

This is the code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        int[] data = {12, 14, 13, 15, 19, 17, 16, 11, 18, 20};
        System.out.println("Compute some result for the Array : " + Arrays.toString(data));
        int[] result = someAlgorithm(data);
        System.out.println("Resulting Array: " + Arrays.toString(result));
    }
 
    private static int[] someAlgorithm(int[] data) {
        int size = data.length;
        int[] result = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                total += data[j];
            }
            int average = total / (i + 1);
            result[i] = average;
            System.out.println("Average for iteration " +  i + " is: " + average);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running this code?  The algorithm is not related to sorting in any way. It just sums two first elements of the input array `12+14` and then just divides it by the index (it's supposed to calculate an average but it is definitely not the average).  The complexity of this algorithm is O(N).

Comment: @Alex I'd say you're wrong there. The inner loop runs `1+2+3` -> `O(N^2)` times. And it is indeed average, `result[i]` stores the average of the first `i` elements.

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora, my comment regarding complexity referred to the original code as you can see in the edit history, where the nested loop used a constant value.

Comment: It is not a sorting algorithm, you might want to run this first

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the method `someAlgorithm()` is that it takes an array `data` as input and creates another array `result` of the same size, where `result[i]` stores the average (as an `int`) of the first `i` elements of the input array.

> Note that you can keep a running sum of the elements seen so far and
> reduce the complexity of this algorithm to `O(N)` fairly easily.

Also, as @Alex mentioned in the comments, this really has nothing to do with sorting and is **not** a type of sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of [algorithmic complexity](https://devopedia.org/algorithmic-complexity):

1. [Space Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity)
2. [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

As you said, this algorithm runs in `O(N²)`, and this is in regards to *time complexity*. This is because the time the algorithm will take to run increases with the square of the `size` variable. As for *space complexity*, it runs in `O(N)`, as the space (that is, the amount of memory) it takes up increases linearly with the `size` variable.

To see which time complexity an algorithm runs in, you need to look at how many nested loops there are, and how long they run for depending on the input.

To see which space complexity an algorithm runs in, you need to look at when and where data is stored, and how much of it is stored depending on the input.